# Setting Default Categories on Publish Page

Tags: categories

Is there a way to pre-select categories when publishing an item? For instance, I have several category groups for my news articles. I want to preselect several of these every time; but it would be great if EE (either natively, or via a plugin) could preselect these for me?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, it's native functionality!

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#default-category

Comment: If i recall correctly, it is limited to one category. You could probably use an accessory to set several via javascript (if entry_id is empty = new entry).